# How to replace dashes with spaces, and double dashes with dashes?

Tags: regex, meteor

I am writing a CRUD of people in Meteor, and I want pretty URLs like

www.mysite.com/John-Doe.

(Actually, my real preference would be
www.mysite.com/JohnDoe, but the implementation might be a bit more difficult.)

In order to accomplish that, I need to be able to translate from "John-Doe" to "John Doe" and from "John-Doe--Smith"John Doe-Smith".

I could of course use a preliminary replacement of "--" to some temporary character, but looking for a more elegant solution.

(Edit: after writing this, I just realized that I can sanitize the name to collapse multiple white spaces and dashes into one first; but I am now curious about the more generic answer).

Comment: Or is there a prettier way to encode names?

Comment: Tried `"a--b".replace(/-(?!-)/g, ' ')`, but it returns `"a- b"`. What's the regex for replacing all *single* dashes, while leaving multiple dashes alone?

Comment: I ended up replacing spaces with underscores, not dashes: "John_Doe-Smith". Still, my question stands.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at the [underscore.string](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string) library, available to Meteor with `meteor add underscorestring:underscore.string`.

```
// Replace dashes with spaces:
s.humanize("no-dash");
// => "no dash"

// Dashes to camel case:
s.camelize("John-Doe");
// => "JohnDoe"

// Double dashes to single dashes:
s.replaceAll("John-Doe--Smith", "--", "-");
// => "John-Doe-Smith"

// Join two names with dashes:
s.join("-", "John", "Doe");
// => "John-Doe"
```

In a number of cases there are multiple ways to get to the same result, including methods more elegant or tailored than those above.